# PnPCore - How to add Azure AD group or M365 group to SharePoint group?

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint

I am trying to add an existing Azure AD group & M365 group to SharePoint group **using PnPCore** but I am struggling to find anything that explains how I can do that.

```
var siteGroup = await newSiteContext.Web.SiteGroups.FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.LoginName == "some group");
await siteGroup.AddUserAsync("someuser@domain.com");
```

Using above I can add users to the group however not sure how can I add Azure AD group or M365 group.

I have tried -

```
await siteGroup.AddUserAsync("GROUP_NAME@domain.com"); //m365 group
await siteGroup.AddUserAsync("GROUP_NAME"); //Azure AD group
```

but it did not work. If anyone can help me with it, that would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS - Same question is also posted on Github - https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/discussions/783 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [jansenbe (Bert Jansen) · GitHub](https://github.com/jansenbe) . Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> You can add Azure AD security groups or members of the Microsoft 365 groups. For that, correctly format the `loginName`, GUIDs are the object ids of the respective Azure AD objects.

```
// Add an Azure AD security group
await addedGroup.AddUserAsync("c:0t.c|tenant|c8e69a24-a625-48d7-b80b-c9656b9d4030");

// Add an Microsoft 365 group (members)
await addedGroup.AddUserAsync("c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|45dfc99d-a4a5-419d-ad79-013eed517fb2");
```

References: [How to add Azure AD group or M365 group to SharePoint group? · Discussion #783 · pnp/pnpcore · GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/discussions/783#discussioncomment-2325781) and [Working with users | PnP Core SDK](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/security-users.html#sharepoint-users)